# Regional dialect or just improper grammar? Eating on leftovers or just eating leftovers

Tags: prepositions, american-english, dialects

On several occasions I have heard white people from the deep south part of the United States (Louisiana to Georgia) say that they will be eating ON leftovers, instead of just eating leftovers.

For example, I would normally say: I'm going to eat the leftover spaghetti all week.

However, some people say: "I'm going to eat **on** the leftover spaghetti all week."

Clearly, you don't eat ON spaghetti, but it may be a regional thing that is acceptable. Can anyone explain this?

NOTE: Also, I recently heard Maggie, a southern character presumably from Georgia on the TV show Walking Dead, say "I'll think on it", which made me think it might be a southern dialect thing, as opposed to just improper English.

Comment: Sounds like "eating on" means "subsisting on", which is an interesting alteration/widening of *eating.*

Comment: As an Australian I have never heard anyone use the phrase "eating on" although I suppose it could be similar to "feeding on".

Comment: Both good points! It makes a lot more sense in that context. Also, "nibbling on." Hopefully there is some southern US english professor that can expand on this.

Comment: In the cited context, alternative verbs such as ***dine, subsist, survive, live, exist*** all require the preposition ***on*** linking the foodstuff to the verb. But so far as I know only non-native speakers would do that with ***eat***, which is *transitive*.

Comment: SAE and AAVE speakers can't seem to get enough of *on*. They don't drive down to the lake, they drive on down to the lake.They don't just love or hate someone, they might love on or hate on them too. And they'll do it on yesterday, on today, and on tomorrow.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes on this question, this is a question about regional dialects vs grammar both of which are within the scope of this forum and clearly listed as such in the Help Center.

Comment: Possibly because the question does not show what efforts you have already made to research possible answers.

Comment: @MetaEd Can you suggest where one might do that for such spoken word examples?

Comment: "Clearly you don't eat **on** spaghetti" ... I suppose you don't chew on spaghetti, either?

Comment: For the record "I'll think on it" is completely normal and unnotable in Pacific Northwest English.

Comment: "I'll think on it" is known, but a bit archaic sounding in most dialects of UK English, just for the record. "I'm going to eat ON..." would not be clearly understood by speakers of those dialects, though. "..eat on..." would only be used to describe where the eating occurred: "I'm going to eat on a boat...". To "dine on", "subsist on", "live on", spaghetti, are all fine here..

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with "eating on", other than it's not idiomatic.  (Though certainly "Has something been *eating on* you?" *is* idiomatic, throughout most of the US.)  One can certainly *eat on* a cob of corn.

Comment: (What could possibly make it "improper grammar", even if it isn't idiomatic?)

Comment: I would take "eating on" to mean like eating small amounts, almost like "nibbling on."  I'd think it also implies they don't like the food.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As a native speaker of a 'deep south' dialect, I believe I can provide a fairly authoritative answer.

*Eat* is inherently telic—unmodified it implicates (although it does not entail) complete consumption of its object. Consequently, a futurive construction such as *I will eat* or *I'm going to eat* is implicitly perfective.

*On* is added in my dialect to explicitly cancel those implications: the speaker claims that he will eat portions of the spaghetti at intervals throughout the coming week, without necessarily consuming the whole of it.

(However, "I'm going to eat ...", falls oddly on my ear; it suggests (again, in my dialect) that the speaker is announcing his *firm intention* of dining on the spaghetti. A more likely construction would be "I'm going to ***be eating*** on the leftover spaghetti all week.")

*Eating on* is not by any means a fixed idiom in my dialect. What we have here is, rather, a regionally widespread use of *Verb on Object* instead of bare *Verb Object* to provide an explicitly imperfective sense: for instance, we *sand on* a board for a while or *consider on* a topic without coming to any conclusion. This use of *on* is by no means unknown in Standard English (whatever the hell that is), where one may *nibble on* the hors-d'oeuvres or *work on* an assigned task; but the use is more widespread and the construction more productive in the South.

Comment: Your wording implicitly implies (or implicates) that the phenomenon does indeed occur in your variety. But you also imply/implicate that the phenomenon should be universal in English. As it is not universal, can you clarify how you explanation does or does not work for all varieties of English and for your particular one where the phenomenon occurs?

Comment: @Mitch I've added a paragraph.

Comment: This is an exemplary answer!

Comment: I'm going to push back. I recognize your explanation of this use of 'on', having grown up speaking a (weakly distinguished) variety of SAE. Outside of that narrow context, the use sounds strange to me (like the OP). I tend to interpret the 'on' not as part of a phrasal verb but as a real preposition heading a comedically locative prepositional phrase in this case ("Where will you be eating?" "On the spaghetti, I'm going to be eating __on the leftover spaghetti__.". So how do you account for this standard interpretation in your answer.

Comment: I love it! Great answer and comments, I'm with Mitch, I'd like a little more clarification. Eating on spaghetti all week gives me an image of a Gollum-like creature hunched over spilled spaghetti on the floor. :) Although, I see the parallels with "nibbling on" and "feeding on" as previously mentioned.

Comment: @Mitch A chronic problem here and on ELL is questions that present odd brief utterances divorced from their discourse context: each reader makes their own sense of the utterance by inventing a context, and then finds it very difficult to enter into an entirely different context imagined by the next reader. I read this and immediately had a vision of the speaker staring in dismay at a vast pot of cold spaghetti and seeing himself eating on it (non-southerners might say "eating **at** it") for a week.

Comment: I can confirm that "eating on" as StonyB explains it, is common in the parts of Atlanta and rural North Carolina I frequent - much like snack on and nibble on - meaning to consume **part** of something. *Those buzzards have been eating on that carcass since the weekend* is another typical use.

Comment: I find your analysis about 'on' being a marker about perfect and continuing aspect to be just right -for that dialect-. I think I wrote my second comment without noticing the restriction to 'my dialect'.  I'm not sure the semantics of 'eat' in GenAmE is 'telic' (it may be, it may not... OK probably is). I suppose the 'imperfect version in GenAmE would be to change the lexical item: 'I'm going to snack on the spaghetti' (where 'snack on' is not a phrasal verb), or 'to eat some of...' which implies _not_ finishing it.

Comment: @Mitch Mea culpa -- the *my dialect* pieces were in fact added in response to your very apropos comment.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the premise of this answer. Eat does seem to be telic when applied to a countable object: for example, "I could eat a horse" definitely implies eating the whole thing. But it's not telic when applied to an uncountable object: "I could eat horse" means "I would be prepared to consume a portion of horse flesh" and "I will eat spaghetti" certainly doesn't imply "I will eat all the spaghetti in the world." So, at least in "standard" Englishes, there's no suggestion that "I'm going to eat the leftover spaghetti all week" means that all the leftovers will be eaten.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Quite so: the character of the object influences our interpretation of the verb's aspect--and vice versa: "I will eat spaghetti" is interpreted "I will eat [some spaghetti]". But in OP's sentence the object is definite (*the leftover spaghetti*). ... I don't mean to suggest that the *on* here is necessary to enforce the desired reading--it's more an emphatic flourish to emphasize the desired reading.

Comment: @StoneyB OK, I agree that there's a difference between "I will eat spaghetti" and "I will eat the spaghetti" (and that distinction doesn't change if the spaghetti is leftover).

Comment: @Mitch As opposed to explicitly implies? ;)

Comment: I'm a fellow Deep South guy and I agree with this answer.  I regularly use the construction, too.

Comment: Funny - mid-Atlantic native AmE speaker here, and if I were looking at a huge amount of leftover spaghetti, I would be more likely to say, "*I'll be eating **off** this for weeks!*"

Comment: +1. Out of curiosity -- Standard English sometimes uses "from" to cancel the telicity of "eat" ("The casserole was delicious, but everyone who ate from it got sick"), but I'm not sure it works in a context like the OP's example. Does your 'deep south' dialect have "eat from" as well as "eat on", and if so, do you perceive a difference between them?

Comment: @ToddWilcox The *off* (or *off of / offa / offn*) version exists in my dialect as well, but it would tend to signify that I am focusing on the spaghetti as the source of my nourishment rather than as a corpus to be consumed.

Comment: @ruakh *Eat from* and *eat of* are rather literary where I come from; we'd be more like to express this with *off / offa / offn*. See Todd Wilcox's comment and my response.

Answer (score 9):

I'm from the edge of the U.S. South (Texas), and I've never heard "eat on" used in connection with actual eating, so this must be a Deep South locution, to judge from StoneyB's interesting answer.

---

***'Eat on' as a slang idiom***

On the other hand the idiomatic expression "What's eating on you/him/her?" (as a variant of "What's eating you/her/him?") is widespread in Texas and I believe that I've also heard it used in other parts of the United States where I've lived (Washington, D.C., New York City, and San Francisco Bay Area). But it's unclear to me whether it arose independently of the literal dialectal sense of "eating on" or is a unique offshoot of the Southern wording that caught on everywhere.

J.E. Lighter, *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1994) has this relevant entry for the verb *eat*:

> **eat** *v.* **1.** to annoy, bother, or vex.—occ[asionally] constr[ued] with *on*. [First citation, followed by citations involving "eat on":] **1892** S[tephen] Crane, *Maggie* 36: "Well," he growled, "what's eatin' yehs?" ... **1918** Gibbons *Thought Wouldn't Fight* 99: What's eating on you, kid? ... **1937** Steinbeck *Mice & Men* 59: What's Eatin' on Curley? **1939** O'Brien *One Way Ticket* 8: What the hell's eatin' on you now, fella? ... **1961** Terry *Old Liberty* 31: I listened and tried not to let their talk eat on me too bad.

The 1918 instance of "eating on" is from Floyd Gibson, [*"And They Thought We Wouldn't Fight"*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CcoLAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA99&dq=%22eating+on+you+kid%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_5J-RnbTWAhVEwVQKHXR_BQMQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22eating%20on%20you%20kid%22&f=false) (1918) where it appears in the context of a conversation in a military barrack room between the author and an American named Budd English, whom the author identifies as having a "quaint Southwestern wit":

> "That's Kid Ferguson, the pug," English whispered to me, and then in louder tones, he enquired, "What's **eating on** you, kid?"
>
> "Aw. this bunk in the paper," replied Ferguson. Then he glared at me and enquired, "Did you write this stuff?"

---

***Early Google Books matches for 'eat on' used in a literal sense***

A slightly earlier instance of "eat on" in its literal sense appears in M.A. Yothers, "[Bud Weevils and Other Bud-eating Insects of Washington](https://books.google.com/books?id=uasaDEYFncQC&pg=PA21&dq=%22eating+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi09c3cnLTWAhWrllQKHZ3sCJsQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22eating%20on%22&f=false)" (February 1916):

> The writer collected many specimens of this weevil on one- and two-year-old apple trees at Brewster, Washington, in April and May, 1911 and 1912. They were also found abundant on the wild sunflower, *Balsmorrhiza sagittata*, which grows in many parts of the sagebrush region in great abundance. At Brewster, Washington, where so many of these weevils were found the sunflower was very plentiful just outside the young orchards. It is quite certain that *Mylacus saccatus* feeds at least to a considerable extent on this wild sunflower, for on some of the flower heads the flowers were largely eaten away. In several instances they were observed **eating on** the flowers. Although many of the flower heads were examined no eggs or larvae of the weevils were found on or in them.

In context, it seems clear that "eating on" is equivalent to "eating at" or simply "eating," since the weevils are not being described as consuming a meal procured elsewhere on the flowers. The Washington in question is Washington state in the U.S. Pacific Northwest, not Washington, D.C., in the Mid-Atlantic Region.

An intriguing very early instance of "eat on" appears in "[Habits [of the Locust] at Night](https://books.google.com/books?id=TydSAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA209&dq=%22eat+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijqYDnobTWAhXjsFQKHZ8iAIc4ChDoAQgsMAE#v=onepage&q=%22eat%20on%22&f=false)," in *First Annual Report of the United States Entomological Commission for the Year 1877 Relating to the Rocky Mountain Locust* (1878):

> Alden, Freeborn County [Minnesota].—Remain on the ground unless disturbed. **Eat on** what they light on.—{[Stephen] Cross [& Albert Lea, of Freeborn County]

The telegraphic style of this note is a complication here, but "eat on" again seems to mean "eat at" or "eat." Minnesota in in the northern Midwest of the United States.

From "[Mrs. Grundy on the Adulteration of Food](https://books.google.com/books?id=juVbAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA54&dq=%22eats+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPjbzrp7TWAhVCl1QKHeeKAwc4ChDoAQgyMAI#v=onepage&q=%22eats%20on%22&f=false)," in the English periodical *Punch*, volume 28 (1855), we have this instance:

> Your pickles and preserves yon stains bright green for to draw people's eyes on 'em,/ Whereby they verdigris contains, and them as **eats on** 'em they pisen 'em.

It isn't clear whether "eats on 'em" here is a dialectal form of "eats of them" or whether "eats on" is equivalent to "eats" alone.

And jumping back another couple of centuries, we have this instance from Ben Jonson, [*The Magnetick Lady; or Humours Reconciled*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SRhFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA625&dq=%22envious+sir+moth+that+eats+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje5o3apbTWAhWLq1QKHdsSCc4Q6AEINjAC#v=onepage&q=%22envious%20sir%20moth%20that%20eats%20on%22&f=false) (1632/1641):

> *Compass.* Thou malicious knight,/ Envious sir Moth, that **eats on** that which feeds thee,/ And frets her goodness that sustains thy being;/ What company of mankind would own thy brotherhood,/ But as thou hast a title to her blood,/ Whom thy ill-nature hath chose out t'insult on,/ And vex thus, for an accident inher house,/ As if it were her crime! good innocent lady.

Here "eats on" appears to be a synonym of "feeds on" as biologists (and others) use that term today.

Overall, Google Books searches turned up very few matches for "eat on" in the literal sense of "eat." The fact that three of the four earliest matches involve the feeding habits of insects (moths, locusts, and weevils) suggests that "eating on" may have some sense of nibbling. But the sample size is vanishingly small.

Comment: Google Ngram does turn up some examples of "eatin' on", though, including one in a book of Southern Appalachian banjo songs--"Old Molly Hare, what you doin' there, Sittin' on a hillside, eatin' on a bear." (And others.)

Answer (score 0):

As a UK native speaking British English we are more likely to use the antonym 'off' rather than 'on'.

Having had a party which we massively over-catered for, we might say 'I see we'll be living off leftovers this week'! Living relates to eating and the off indicates we will be eating a portion of the food each day.

Google Books has a number of references to living 'off' leftovers.

Comment: Strangely, I think you might say "live off" and "dine on".

Comment: You seem to be claiming that we'd "eat off spaghetti leftovers all week", and that seems completely wrong to me, as a native British speaker. To eat off something means to use that thing [in lieu of a plate](http://wewantplates.com/). Yes, we could "live off" (or "live on") leftovers but the question is specifically asking about "eat on".

Comment: I can see the similarities between "eating on leftovers" vs "eating off leftovers."

Comment: "indicates we will be eating a portion of the food each day." I think that is indeed what "eating on" means, i.e. eating small amounts little by little.

Comment: @RobinSalih Where as I would say "live on" and "eat off".

Answer (score 0):

Out in California I hear constructs such a "Munching on popcorn."

There is a John Mellencamp song called "Jack and Diane." The first part of the lyrics mentions "suckin' on a chili dog":

"A little ditty 'bout Jack & Diane
Two American kids growing up in the heart land
Jack he's gonna be a football star
Diane debutante in the back seat of Jacky's car
Suckin' on chili dog outside the Tastee Free ..."

Comment: You're right—many verbs related to eating commonly take _on_ or _at_: _munch_, _gnaw_, _nibble_, and _chew_, for example. But in much of the United States, _eat on_ is not a common construction to describe actual (not figurative) eating.

Answer (score 0):

The owl and the pussycat 'dined upon mince/and slices of quince/which they ate with a runcible spoon' If they didn't finished it off they could I suppose have dined on the leftovers after they washed the runcible spoon. The verb "to eat" doesn't usually take a preposition in standard English.